# ASP.NET Form Authenticaion

Tags: asp.net

I have created ASP.NET project and connect it to database. After I just added Login and Register control. Something like:

```
    <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" 
        DestinationPageUrl="~/Users/UserAccount.aspx">
    </asp:Login>
```

Actually it works! It does registration and login operation. But HOW? Where is a code, where is SQL statement? I don't see anything related to that. Could you please explain me how it works? and how do I modify say registration control if I need extra information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are built in controls that are already part of the framework.  Take a look at this link if you are wanting to make it more of a custom registration process.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478962.aspx

It may also help you to understand whats going on.